# Can't figure out why sqlite query isn't returning the right result

Tags: java, sqlite

I have this sqlite database which I can run the query "select * from barcode where barcode='CFMS-ZUFH-WRVY-EXAA' and get a single row return. Yet in my Java application when I run pretty much the same sql, it's returning an empty resultset. The variables last, email, etc. are JTextFields though the problem is before them. The if statement doesn't even execute and if I run rs.next() before it and set if (true) I get an error saying ResultSet is closed.

```
try {
    db.dbopen(config.getdbfolder(),config.getdbname()); 
    // barcode-barcode.replaceAll("\\s","");
    ResultSet rs=db.query("select * from barcode where barcode=?",barcode);

    if (rs.next()) {
        first.setText(rs.getString("first_name"));
        System.out.println(rs.getString("first_name"));
        last.setText(rs.getString("last_name"));
        email.setText(rs.getString("email"));
        phone.setText(rs.getString("phone"));
        subject.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("subject"));
        Boolean selected;
        if (rs.getString("baronly").equals("false")) selected=false;
        else selected=true;
        barcodebox.setSelected(selected);   
        update=true;

    } 
    db.conn.close();

} catch ( SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's the method query.

```
public ResultSet query(String sql, String barcode) throws SQLException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    PreparedStatement prep =conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    prep.setString(1, barcode);

    ResultSet rs= prep.executeQuery();  
    prep.close();
    return rs;
}
```

Comment: `if (rs.next()) {` shouldn't it be `while (rs.next()) {`?

Comment: @Smit nope, it doesn't have to be. rs.next() is just checking if any row was returned

Comment: No there's only one result

Comment: @Codeguy007 cursor is initially pointing before the first row. So executing next() is going to check if it has returned any result

Comment: @TemporaryNickName No kidding. That isn't my problem.

Comment: @Codeguy007 hmm what?

Comment: You are tell me something I already know and it's not relevant to my problem other than that rs.next() was returning false when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `query` method, you close the `PreparedStatement` before you return the `ResultSet`.  According to the [Javadocs for `close`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29):

> Note:When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object,
>   if one exists, is also closed.

Don't close your `PreparedStatement` in `query`, close it after you use the `ResultSet`.  I would remove the `query` method and place its code inline with the rest of your code, so that you still have the reference to `PreparedStatement` to close after you're done with the `ResultSet`.

And as @Reimeus has already mentioned, assign the result of `replaceAll` back to `barcode`.

Comment: Yeah it's not working like that. If I comment out prep.close() in query the previous use of the function query fails. I will try replacing query with the code inline and see if I have better luck.

Comment: I didn't say "don't close it at all".  You'll have to rearrange your code so that you can close it after you have processed the `ResultSet`.

Comment: Never mind, I had changed something that reversed the logic on the previous use of query so it was working despite query returning nothing. I moved the whole code inline and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Your intended barcode may still have whitespaces. Assign it to the result of `replaceAll`:

```
barcode = barcode.replaceAll("\\s","");
```

Comment: shoot, didn't see that one XD

Comment: You don't need to worry about that line. barcode is final so I can't change it's value anyway. I was just try that to see if spaces were a problem in the variable but that's not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So here is the finalised answer from both @Reimeus   @rgettman.

```
        try {
            db.dbopen(config.getdbfolder(),config.getdbname()); 
            //you need to set this replaceAll return value to original variable
            barcode = barcode.replaceAll("\\s","");

            //make prep statement here in order to close it in the finally block
            PreparedStatement prep =conn.prepareStatement("select * from barcode where barcode=?");

            //modify query function to accept prepared statement instead of a string
            ResultSet rs=db.query(prep ,barcode);

            if (rs.next()) {
                first.setText(rs.getString("first_name"));
                System.out.println(rs.getString("first_name"));
                last.setText(rs.getString("last_name"));
                email.setText(rs.getString("email"));
                phone.setText(rs.getString("phone"));
                subject.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("subject"));
                Boolean selected;
                if (rs.getString("baronly").equals("false")) selected=false;
                else selected=true;
                barcodebox.setSelected(selected);   
                update=true;

            } 
            db.conn.close();

        } catch ( SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
         //finally you close prepared statement. note that closing prep also closes 
//resultset and closing connection won't clean up resultset nor prep according to most of 
//stackoverflow answers. However, it is recommended to close both resultset and prepared 
//statement explicitly
         prep.close();
         rs.close();
       }
```

This must work given the condition your database table has correct values that matches where clause condition. Please double check if your query successfully executes when you test run it.